# Dynamically adding date to a file name in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm using this cron task to run a job and write the logs into a file.

```
0 */9 * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate 
&& cd /opt/python/current/app/ 
&& source /opt/python/current/env 
&&  python manage.py parse_sources > /var/log/parse_sources.log 2>&1
```

Now the name of the file here is `parse_sources.log`. I want to make append the date to it dynamically when the cron runs in a specific format, viz, `parse_sources_apr_4_2019.log`

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need it specifically with a apr_4_2019 sort of format or would something like 20190404 suffice?

Comment: @NickVitha actually filename_20190404.log will work too.

Comment: Like `> /var/log/parse_sources_$(date +"%b_%-d_%Y").log 2>&1`?

Comment: @JNevill beat me to it.

Comment: @JNevill Be careful -- `%` has special meaning in crontab lines, it needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```
python manage.py parse_sources > /var/log/parse_sources_$(date +"%b_%-d_%Y").log 2>&1
```